# Retrieving data from several input fields with the same name

Tags: php, forms, post, input

I have a form that you dynamically creates new input fields (type=hidden) which when the form is sent should be retrieved by my php code. However, by the reason that the number of input fields can differ I gave them the same name. The problem however is that I don't know how to retrieve it, or more correctly, what to do with what's retrieved.

**from the form:**

```
...
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject' value='0' />
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject' value='2' />
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject' value='3' />
...
```

**from php code (listView.php):**

```
private $m_newListObject = 'newListObject';
...
if (isset($_POST[$this->newListObject])) {
    $listObjects = $_POST[$this->m_newListObject];
}
```

**from php code (listModel.php):**

```
//Below doesn't work because $listObjects isn't an array

foreach ($listObjects as $listObject) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO listElement (listElemName, listId) VALUES(?, ?)";

    $stmt = $this->m_db->Prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param('si', $listObject, $listId);

    $ret = $this->m_db->RunInsertQuery($stmt);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject[]' value='0' />
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject[]' value='1' />
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject[]' value='2' />
<input type='hidden' name='newListObject[]' value='3' />
```

And use `$_REQUEST['newListObject']` as an `array()` now.

Comment: Thanks! So I should retrieve them without the "[]"? Should I use $_REQUEST instead of $_POST or what do you mean?

Comment: @holyredbeard `$_POST` if you `POST`, `$_GET` if you `GET`, `$_REQUEST` if I don't know :) `[]` turns them into arrays in PHP. So you treat `$_WHATEVER['newListObject']` as an array not a scalar. And without `[]`. That's just in HTML to make PHP give you arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you call them `name="newListPObject[]"` PHP will receive them as an array that can be looped over.